# Postgres trigger function to update aggregated result in another table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables. Table x and table y. Table x gets updated everyday. I wish to update the table y as soon as new data is inserted in Table x. Table y contains the aggregated value of all the update in Table x each day.
Date is in Date type and the rest of the two column are of real type.
Table_x can be updated daily and table_y should be updated automatically.

Table `x`:

```
Date    Sales    product
12/12/2017   4000   2
12/12/2017   3000   1
12/12/2017   2000   1
12/12/2017   5000   3
11/12/2017   1000   3
11/12/2017   2000   4
```

Table `y` (to be as updated as shown below):

```
Date   Sales   product
12/12/2017   14000   7
11/12/2017   3000    7
```

I wrote the trigger function as shown below but it updates each item rather than aggregated value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rec_insert_table_y()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO table_y ("Date","Sales","product")
SELECT NEW."Date",(sum(NEW."Sales")),(sum(NEW."product"))
GROUP BY NEW."Date";
RETURN NEW;
```

Trigger Function :

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_into_table_y
AFTER INSERT
ON public.table_x
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.rec_insert_table_y();
```

Comment: I can't see your trigger definition nor table definitions nor Postgres version anywhere. And your function is incomplete, too. Also missing: basic info: Can new products be inserted in table `x`? or just new rows for existing products? Please [edit] to complete info.

Comment: @Erwin: Update the definition as you have suggested. My Postgres version is "PostgreSQL 9.5.3". Yes new products are daily inserted in Table_x.

Comment: This part of my comment went unanswered: `Can new products be inserted in table x? or just new rows for existing products? `

Answer (score 3):

You can write a trigger that updates the aggregate value if exists or inserts if not.

Also you must be aware updates and deletes in the 'x' table:

```
create function y_x_trg() returns trigger
  language plpgsql
as
$body$
declare
  row_exists boolean;
begin
  if tg_op<>'INSERT' then
    update y 
      set sales = y.sales - old.sales,
          product = y.product - old.product
      where y.date = old.date
      returning true into row_exists;
  end if;
  if tg_op<>'DELETE' then
    update y 
      set sales = y.sales + new.sales,
          product = y.product + new.product
      where y.date = new.date
      returning true into row_exists;
    if row_exists is not true then
      insert into y values (new.date, new.sales, new.product);
    end if;
    return new;
  else
    return null;
  end if;
end;
$body$;

create trigger y_x_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON x
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE y_x_trg();
```

You can see a running example at http://rextester.com/FVR79644

Comment: Emilio thanks for the update but does it AGGREGATE(sum) the sales and products for each day into target table..?? . I thought we will have to use the GROUP BY method some how on Date column.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are write. I missunderstand. I supouse product was an id. Your example is clear, it was my fault. I edited the answer to reflect that ´y´ table has only date as the PK